# Can pinterest have more than one user-defined event?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

In the Pinterest developer docs at https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/event-code it mentions a "user-defined" event type.  I have also seen such an event called a "partner-defined" event elsewhere.  Specifically, the page says of the "user-defined" event:

> Add any additional event that you’ve defined for the purpose of audience targeting. Unique events aren’t available for conversion reporting. Keep in mind that whitespace will be trimmed from raw event names passed through the tag

From his description it's unclear if as a developer I can define multiple user-defined events or only one.  It would seem weird that it could only be one, so I initially assumed that I could define multiple.  But based on how these events are showing up in the Pinterest account once I transmit them via the `pintrk` javascript calls, I'm starting to wonder if only one user-define event is allowed.

Here are some details of some of my user-defined events:
I have some events similar to:
`pintrk('track', 'AuthSeller', {'SellerId': 12345})`
`pintrk('track', 'AddToWishlist', {'unitPrice': 50.99})`

plus a few other user defined events.

What I see in the Event History for the conversion tag is a list of the standard events and only one partner-defined event aka user-defined event (which is the top).  It looks like this:

[image: Event History]

Interestingly the properties that show up for the `AuthSeller` event actually come from the `AuthSeller` event, the `AddToWishlist` event and a few other user-defined events I sent from the dev site.

Notice that it shows the first event as "partner-defined event: AuthSeller" and it shows properties that come from the `AuthSeller`, `AddToWishlist` and other of my user-defined events.

So the properties of all my user-defined events are being reported under a single user-defined event, and it appears to be the first user-defined event that my dev site sent to Pinterest for this conversion tag.

First I thought this was just an anomaly with how the event history was being reported. But then I saw similar weirdness when trying to use the user-defined events to define an audience.

If I try to use the `AddToWishlist` user-defined event to define an audience in a Pinterest business account, the `AddToWishlist` event does not show up and in fact the only user-defined event that does is the `AuthSeller` event (again the first user-define event my dev site sent Pinterest) In the screen shot below I have typed and `A` so the UI is showing all the events that start with A and `AddToWishlist` is not there.

[image: Audience Dialog]

I've searched high and low to try to find examples or docs or blog posts about using user-defined events with Pinterest.  But there doesn't seem to be much out there.  And what Pinterest says amounts to the text I quoted early.

If you have any experience with this and could share some insights I'd be grateful.  Can Pinterest have more than one user-defined event and use them or is it limited to a single user-defined event?

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet.  The question is worth an upvote, don't ya think? ;-)